# Create click listener in for-loop for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<ol id="cat-list"></ol>
<div id="cat">
    <h2 id="cat-name"></h2>
    <div id="cat-count"></div>
    <img id="cat-img" src="">
</div>
```

Javascript file

```
var cats = [{
    name: 'Meebo',
    clickCount: 0,
    imgSrc: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/junku/12752007/in/album-  303691/'
}, {
    name: 'Mrs. B',
    clickCount: 0,
    imgSrc: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/junku/12752033/in/album-303691/'
}]

var f = function () {

    for(var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        var cat = cats[i];
        $('#cat-list').append('<li>' + cat.name + '</li>');
        $('li').on('click', function () { // Two alerts for first cat?
            alert('hello');
        });
    }
}
f();
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when the user clicks on either cat name, a single alert fires. But when the first cat is clicked, it fires off two alerts. I can sort of see why, but don't have a solution. What my code is attempting to do is lay down a click listener for both cat names in the for-loop.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/gsd2yomy/)

Comment: What does `$('li')` do? Answer that and you will know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the event is bound to all the `li` elements present in DOM when binding the event.

Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#cat-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    console.log('Hello');
});
```

Here's complete code:

```
var cats = [{
    name: 'Meebo',
    clickCount: 0,
    imgSrc: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/junku/12752007/in/album-  303691/'
}, {
    name: 'Mrs. B',
    clickCount: 0,
    imgSrc: 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/junku/12752033/in/album-303691/'
}];

$('#cat-list').on('click', 'li', function () {
    console.log('Hello');
});

var f = function () {
    for(var i = 0, len = cats.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#cat-list').append('<li>' + cats[i].name + '</li>');
    }
};
f();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/gsd2yomy/1/)

Comment: If I alter your code and remove the 'li' from the listener, it works as well. Is it needed then?

Comment: @MatthewMoon Yes, it is needed. It works because of event bubbling. The event on `li` is bubbled up in the DOM to the parent `ul` and event handler of it is executed.